# I took my iPhone 4 apart and now the display isn't working

Tags: iphone

so I was *trying* to replace the front of my phone. I didn't need a new LED display because just the top corner of the glass was chipped.

Well, I took the phone apart shortly to find out that it's *impossible* to remove the LED from the front glass so I just put the phone back together the way it was.

Now when I turn the phone on, it just sits with a black glow. However, *it does respond to the power button*, but it displays no color other than black. So you either get a matted black (off) or a glowing black (on).

Has anyone ever run into this before? ***Thanks.***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur with Jan's [suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/42523/11791), and direct you to iFixit's [Installing iPhone 4 Display Assembly](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPhone-4-Display-Assembly/). Perhaps if you repeat the procedure, carefully following the instructions in the guide, you can restore the display functionality.

I would also add, at the risk of sounding condescending, that had you done a little research prior to tearing open the device, you would have discovered that the iPhone 4 digitizer is bonded to the outer glass. This was much discussed, and often criticized both because of screen discoloration on new devices (until the "glue" set) and as being anti-DIY repair when the device was first released. Live and learn, I applaud your initiative in opening your device.

Comment: I'll second the sentiment here - re-check all cables. Even large cables need reseating - especially so with short and delicate cables. Also - even trained technicians sometimes have a repair go bad. It could be the simple fact that flexing a cable one too many times (don't touch it if it's not broken) or due to poor luck / skill. The cost of buying a new device is part of doing business and when a repair shop does 100 repairs - that risk is spread among all - not every one fails. When we as consumers are doing a repair - that one in 100 risk hits doesn't matter if it happens on _your_ repair.

Answer (score -2):

You could try putting it into DFU mode (you have to google for it, I don't know the exact procedure) and connect it to iTunes to restore the firmware.

(And the next time you take apart an iDevice on your own, check out ifixit.com. There you can read how to repair the device without killing it.)

Comment: This isn't a repair even apple accomplishes outside a factory setting. The chance of damaging components here is so high, that it's more economical to replace the entire device for iPhone 4 and iPhone 4S front screen breakages.